# Is there a name for these "generalised" Bernoulli processes?

Tags: probability

What I am looking for is if there exists an official name for a "generalized" Bernoulli process, i.e. a sequence of random independent binary variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined over the same probability space, and for which for every $n$ there exists a value $p_n\in [0,1]$ s.t.
$$
X_n =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{with prob. } p_n \\
0 & \text{with prob. } 1-p_n
\end{cases}
$$
A Bernoulli process then would correspond to having $p_n$ equal to a fixed $p$ for every $n$.

What if the binary "statuses" are allowed to change too, i.e. what if for every $n$ there existed $a_n,b_n$ s.t.
$$
X_n =
\begin{cases}
a_n & \text{with prob. } p_n \\
b_n & \text{with prob. } 1-p_n
\end{cases}
\quad ?
$$
Is there a name for such processes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're still Bernoulli processes.

In general, a probability space is a triple $\{\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\}$, where $\Omega$ is the *sample space*, or set of all possible results, $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of events, and $P$, a function that assigns probabilities to events in $\mathcal{F}$.

If your $X_n$ are in the set $\{0,1\}$, then your $\Omega$ is defined as some collection of $0$s and $1$s. However, there's nothing inherently special about $\Omega$ being a collection of $0$s, and $1$s. It could be a collection of bananas and apples, or "bomb hits target"s and "bomb doesn't hit target"s.

In your case, you're just picking "something from the as" or "something from the bs". The fact that the thing from the a's/b's might vary with respect to $n$ only becomes interesting if there are some dynamics to it.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda thought so but wasn't sure, thanks. Then what about the case when the probabilities $p_n$ depend on $n$?

Comment: Then you have a [Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)

Comment: I think it's more than a Markov chain, since $X_n$ does not depend on $X_{n-1}$ but just on the time $n$. I agree we are talking about Markov chains, but before closing the answer I'd like to be sure whether a more specific notation exists or not.

Comment: @AndreasT If the probability changes with time, then you have a [non-stationary random process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process]).

Comment: Yes, but then again what we are talking about is a non-stationary random process where $X_n$ depends on $n$ (that's why it is non-stationary), but _not_ on $X_n$ (so I guess it is more than a Markov chain).

Comment: $n$ is just an index. When you say it depends on $n$, then it either depends on $X_n$, and it is a Markov chain; or it depends on $t_n$, and it is a non-stationary process; or both. Indices are synthetic objects we create to help deal with quantization of some dimension; they are not natural objects that appear explicitly in our formulation. When they do, they are nearly always a result of some convenient choice of time interval (e.g. "let $\Delta t = 1, t_0 = 0$") or state definition.

Comment: I get your point about the time dependency, as for $X_n$ I mistyped it for $X_{n-1}$. I guess I have to conclude that _non-stationary Markov process_ is the best match. Thank you for your patience :)